# Как сделать элементы с промежутком как на скриншоте с помощью одного тега без svg?

Tags: html, css, transform, rotate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данном скриншоте это сделано с помощью svg, но я пытаюсь сделать с помощью тегов. Сразу скажу, да я могу просто сделать +100500 тегов span, но я хочу попробовать сделать с помощью одного тега

Comment: просто циклом выводи тогда в блок какой-то и позицию задавай в зависимости от id

Comment: Ой ё ой, страшные вы вещи хотите сотворить, нельзя же вот так с пользователем, `<svg>` не просто так придумали :)